# Generate 'Random number' variables in JMeter

Tags: random, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

Is it possible to generate 'Random number' variables in JMeter?

1. I have recorded a user journey
2. I have imported the journey into JMeter
3. I have to type in a unique 4digit id within my user journey test case
4. Its default to 2323 at the moment in jmeter

Is there a way of generating a random 4didgit number?
For example thread1: ID: 2323
thread2: 3334
thread3: 5643

Please refer to images below:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) JMeter function

```
${__Random(0000,9999)}
```

> The random function returns a random number that lies between the given min and max values.

- Third parameter can be used as a variable name to save random value

Comment: thanks so much for your help, do i just add it to the 'value' textfield, listed in the image?