# Jmeter: 24-bit random number in test script

Tags: random, jmeter

In my jmeter script: Generate 24-bit random number.  I set `${__time(YMDH)}${random}`.

Do you know of any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate 'Random number' variables in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328356/generate-random-number-variables-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24-bit random number can be:

- [unsigned](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Egermain/PPS/Topics/unsigned_integer.html), in this way you can have values from 0 to FFFFFF in [hexadecimal](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), in this case you can use [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) like `${__Random(0,16777215,)}`
- [signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), in this case you have from `−8388608` to `8388607`, in this case you can use [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) like `${__groovy(new Random().nextInt(8388607 - -8388608) + -8388608,)}`